# Doctrine2 apply function to query parameter

Tags: doctrine-orm

I use the doctrine query builder to build my query.

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select(array('u'))->from('Account', 'a');

-- problem here
$qb->where('lower_unaccent(u.email) LIKE :search');
$qb->setParameter('search', $search['search'] . '%');
```

This works fine, but I would also like to apply the lower_unaccent function to the search parameter.

Is there a way to do this with the query builder?
Because when I do `LOWER_UNACCENT(u.email) LIKE LOWER_UNACCENT(:search)` I get the following error:

```
Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_STRING, got 'LOWER_UNACCENT'
```

Even if I change LOWER_UNACCENT TO LOWER, I get the same error message.

Comment: Did you try, ``$qb->setParameter('search', '%'.$search['search'] . '%');``

Comment: This is not the problem, i want to apply a function on the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$qb->expr()->lower('u.email')` and `$qb->expr()->lower(':search')`. To create the "LIKE" pass those as arguments to `$qb->expr()->like()`.

There doesn't seem to be a unaccent method though, but maybe there is a way to customize this. Let me know how it went.

EDIT:

Looking into lower()'s code, it seems like you can use any function you want like this:

```
new Expr\Func('LOWER', array($x));
```

Answer (score -1):

By default, I'm pretty sure you can't do that.
lower_unaccent is not standard SQL, and as far as I can see, not supported by Doctrine.

What you can do is extend DQL with user-defined functions, which will do whatever you want. It is not so hard to implement. Here is some documentation:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#adding-your-own-functions-to-the-dql-language

Comment: My bad, i haven't been clear enough :( I implemented the lower_unaccent function, this workds fine. But i can't find a way to apply it to the search parameter. eg $qb->where('lower_unaccent(u.email) LIKE lower_unaccent(:search)';

Comment: I tried with dql instead of query builder and I have the same error.